# How to handle structs within solidity any

Tags: solidity, arrays, struct, string

What's the possible workaround for passing an array of strings (not supported by solidity at current time). I am using an array of struct that is state variable to a contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;
contract Person {
struct edu {
string title;
string institute;
string date;
string details;
}
edu[] public education;
constructor (string[] title, string[] institute, string[] date, string[] 
details                         
) public {
for (uint i=0; i<title.length; i++)
edu memory newEdu = edu({
title : title[i],
institute : institute[i],
date : date[i],
details : details[i]
});
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround can be to use the new abi encoder. You need to use an alternative library like [ethers.js](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/109) because web3 didn't support it yet.

The old school solution I've used is to past is to use a byte array with all strings concatenated, first byte is the length and follow the string data.

If you are fancy you can use RLP encoding on the byte array to support other types of data, you will be doing your own encoding/decoding.

Comment: The new abi encoder is not for production right now( in beta).
Would you like to share some code example with 2nd approach.
3rd approach seems promising.

Comment: I recently found this RLP library https://github.com/FourthState/plasma-mvp-rootchain/blob/master/contracts/Libraries/RLP.sol, you can give it a try.

Comment: I have been trying hard but its not working for me its too much buggy (the Library you mentioned). :(